# Is it possible to conditionally add item to OpenStruct?

Tags: ruby

I want to add a string to an openstruct like this:

```
link = link.split(",")
OpenStruct.new(title: link[0].strip, url: link[1].strip)
```

Sometimes, it contains a third variable, which I want to add as well:

```
OpenStruct.new(title: link[0].strip, url: link[1].strip, id: link[2].strip)
```

I could check for `link[2]` and create two `OpenStruct.new`s lines, but is there some way to add just the id afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a hash and modify *that* conditionally. Then unconditionally pass it to OpenStruct.

```
link = link.split(',')
os_args = { title: link[0].strip, url: link[1].strip }
os_args[:id] = link[2].strip if link[2]

OpenStruct.new(os_args)
```

Comment: this seems to work, but when I use link.id i get ["string"]